# Integer division in Octave

Tags: octave

I want to perform an integer division in Octave (I'm using the latest version `5.1.0`). I tired doing `idivide(5, 2, "round")` which should produce `3`. The [Documentation](http://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Integer-Arithmetic.html) says for using `idivide` with `round`:

> Calculate a ./ b with the fractional part rounded towards the nearest integer.

However, the result I get is `2.5000`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** sorry I used the wrong parameter when initially writing the question. Calling the function with `fix` works perfectly fine (e.g. `idivide(5, 2, "fix")` returns `2`), I get the problem when using `round`.

Comment: Do you by any chance have replaced `idivide`? Because it works as expected for me `> idivide(5, 2, "fix") -> ans = 2`

Comment: If your arguments are not actually integers (in Octave the constant `2` is a double-precision floating-point value), then just use `round(5/2)`. `idivide` is explicitly made for integer values (`uint8`, `int16`, etc.).

Comment: In the case of round, it seems like this is an Octave bug. See https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?57278

Comment: incidentally, simply casting the result of a normal division to an int seems to round as you want (i.e. `int64(5/2)` ). Don't forget to cast back to double if that's the type you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: The below is important for Matlab, in Octave the originally posed question (`fix`) gave the expected answer.

At least one of the input arguments must be an integer, hence this should work

```
idivide(5, int32(2), 'fix')
```

But be sure that this is what you want. `idivide` will return an integer class object which has various consequences if you aren't expecting it.

For example compare with an alternative solution which returns a double

```
idivide(5, int32(2), 'fix')*0.9
ans =
 int32
  2

fix(5/2)*0.9
ans =
 1.8000
```

Comment: This is not true. Octave does not care whether the inputs to `idivide` are integers. The error in the question must come from somewhere else.

Comment: The documentation itself clearly casts to integer, did you read it?
https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/idivide.html

Additionally in Matlab `idivide` without casting to integer does not work.

Comment: The example in the documentation casts it to integer, but nowhere in the documentation states that it is required. I have tested the code, read the source, and the whole history of `idivide`. It is not required to cast to integer because `idivide` casts to double internally, makes the operation with double precision, and then casts back to integer.

Comment: Then, as per Octave's own Wiki, since the functionally is different to Matlab this is an Octave bug. [Wiki](https://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#Differences_between_Octave_and_Matlab)

Comment: It is not a bug because it is still Matlab compatible. Things that don't work in Octave but work in Matlab /may/ be a bug, but the other way around is not. Octave has many things that don't work in Matlab, this seems to be another one.

Comment: I disagree. But if you insist you should ask Octave to change the following in their Wiki to not imply commutativity of functionality, `There are still a number of differences between Octave and Matlab, however in general differences between the two are considered as bugs`

Comment: Can we at least agree this answer is incorrect? That Octave does not change its behaviour by casting the input to integers (whether that's a bug or not is irrelevant here), and therefore the OP problem needs to be somewhere else?

Comment: Sure, especially given that the question has changed.